# C# Prepared Statement and multiple queries

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, odbc, prepared-statement

Is it possible to execute multiple queries with the same prepared statement (same `OdbcCommand` object)?

Below is the code I have and is throwing the following exception: `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException was caught
  Message=ERROR [07006] [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0102E  Invalid conversion. SQLSTATE=07006`

```
 ...
        odbcConnection = myConnection.getOdbcConnection();
        odbcConnection.Open();
        odbcCommand = odbcConnection.CreateCommand();
        odbcTrans = odbcConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        odbcCommand.Transaction = odbcTrans;
try{
    odbcCommand.CommandText = queryStatement1();
            odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID1", parameter1);
            odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID2", parameter2);
    ...
    odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID11", parameter3);
    odbcCommand.Prepare();
            odbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


    odbcCommand.CommandText = queryStatement2();
    odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID1", parameter4);
            odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID2", parameter5);
    ...
    odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID13", parameter6);
    odbcCommand.Prepare();
            odbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    odbcTrans.Commit();
} catch(Exception e){ ... }
...
```

Same `OdbcCommand` object, two different queries...

Comment: What does `queryStatement1()` return?

Comment: `queryStatement1()` returns the query string `insert into TABLE (field1,field2...) values (?,?,...)`

Comment: just for reference if you are using an IBM DB, you can possibly get their native .NET data components. Also `addwithvalue` can be evil especially with dates, if you know the type, specify it in the parameter constructor.

Comment: I'm working with IBM DB2. Also, I just changed the way I add the parameters to `odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("?ID7", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = parameter7;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. I just needed to clear the command parameters right before assigning a different query string to the command

```
...
odbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            odbcCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            odbcCommand.CommandText = queryStatement2();
...
```